# Equivalent rest API call for: "heroku pg:credentials DATABASE_URL --app mypgapp"

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-postgres, heroku-api

```
curl -n -X GET https://api.heroku.com/apps/mypgapp/addons/heroku-postgresql
-H "Content-Type: application/json"   
-H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"
```

Returns a JSON with reelevant PG add-on information, but does not provide the connection strings as the CLI provides with the [pg:credentials](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-credentials) command. What I want to get via Heroku REST API is the host, port, dbname, user and password.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

I've found it can be quite useful to look at the debug output of the Heroku CLI. In this case, you can get the query string from the environment variables:

```
DEBUG=1 HEROKU_DEBUG=1 heroku config:get -a mypgapp DATABASE_URL                                                   ❖ ruby-2.3.0
heroku-cli/5.2.12-09f3ecc (darwin-amd64) go1.6.2 /Users/bjeanes/.local/share/heroku/cli/bin/heroku cmd: version
heroku-cli/5.2.12-09f3ecc (darwin-amd64) go1.6.2 /Users/bjeanes/.local/share/heroku/cli/bin/heroku cmd: commands
heroku-cli/5.2.12-09f3ecc (darwin-amd64) go1.6.2 /Users/bjeanes/.local/share/heroku/cli/bin/heroku cmd: config:get
--> GET /apps/mypgapp/config-vars
<-- 200 OK
<-- {"DATABASE_URL":"postgres://REDACTED@ec2-174-129-223-35.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dfbe4e6vs4diqb"}
postgres://REDACTED@ec2-174-129-223-35.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dfbe4e6vs4diqb
```

So, you can then translate that into a `curl` request and get the value out using `jq`:

```
$ curl -n -H 'Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3' \
    https://api.heroku.com/apps/mypgapp/config-vars | jq .DATABASE_URL
postgres://REDACTED@ec2-174-129-223-35.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dfbe4e6vs4diqb
```

This is not the API that `heroku pg:credentials` uses. It actually used Heroku's own [deprecated](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/862) v2 API.